# How to create a table with two foreign keys pointing to the same table using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have the following classes, which I'm trying to store in a database using Entity Framework 6 code first.

Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<WorkItem> WorkItems { get; set; }
}
```

WorkItem:

```
public class WorkItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Person Creator { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see each person can have a number of task. But(!) the task also has a creator that is a person.

I expect the workitem table created by using entity framework's add-migration to have two foreign keys. One so that the workitem can bleong to the WorkItems collection of Person, and one that points to the creator of the Workitem. Like the picture below shows:

[image]

This doesn't seem to be such a weird scenario, but it's causing me loads of problems.

If you just try to create database tables using add-migration the WorkItem is created in the following way:

```
            CreateTable(
            "dbo.WorkItems",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    Creator_Id = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.Creator_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Creator_Id);
```

As you can see there is nothing that makes the Person an owner of its work items here. If I remove the Creator property it works as expected. There seems to be a problem referencing a class when that class is the owner.

Why doesn't this just work out of the box and what is the best way to fix it? Navigation property? Fluent API?

Comment: Where are you "referencing the same table"? Your question and the posted code are not equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I found it hard to give a good title to this question. The end result of my code first should be a table called WorkItem that has two references (foreign keys) to the Person table. One because Person has a list of work items and one because WorkItem has a reference to a person.

Comment: That would mean that you actually store two PersonId in the WorkItem table, is that what you want? It's not clear why you want two references when one is perfectly fine

Comment: Yes, that's right. There should be two references to Person in the Workitem table. I have explained why: "As you can see each person can have a number of task. But(!) the task also has a creator that is a person."

Of course there might be a better way of solving this problem. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your entities using this configuration in your DbContext.OnModelCreating (or better yet, add separate entityconfigurations):

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
   modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.WorkItems).WithMany();
   modelBuilder.Entity<WorkItem>().HasRequired(t => t.Creator).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
 }
```

This will create a table for Person and another for WorkItem and another one to support the many-to-many relationship between Person and WorkItem. It will also create a separate FK in WorkItem to reference Person:

[image]

I couldn't understand your question entirely. I understand that every person can have multiple tasks, but I'm not sure whether a task can be assigned to only one person or multiple people. If you want a one-to-many relationship only, use this configuration:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
   modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.WorkItems).WithOptional();
   modelBuilder.Entity<WorkItem>().HasRequired(t => t.Creator).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
 }
```

This only creates the two tables and in WorkItem two FK-s to reference the Person table; one for the Creator and one so that EF can wire up the references in Person to the WorkItems:

[image]

Comment: Your second scenario is what I'm after. 
What I'd really like to understand is why this can't work out of the box in Entity Framework? The class structure seems pretty simple.

Comment: You would like to express two relationships, but you only specify one half of each. How is EF supposed to know that these two halves do not form a whole? Here's the documentation on what EF knows by itself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx 

If you want a more condensed version, look here: http://dotnetfalcon.com/analyzing-entity-framework-code-first-default-conventions/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like as one to many relationship, so your `Tasks` property should be `ICollection<WorkItem>`, you need to update your both classes.

Your `Person` class would be like:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WorkItem> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

and you would also need to modify your `WorkItem` class to have reference to the `Person` instance who created the `WorkItem`, so `WorkItem` class would be like:

```
public class WorkItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public Guid WorkItemCreatorId{ get; set; }

    public Person Creator { get; set; }

}
```

Now this should generate the correct sql in migrations.

For more on Entity Framework one-to-many relationships, please have [a look here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately.
Does it matter if I use List or ICollection for Tasks on Person?
I don't think you can reference a class ("Person") as a ForeignKey.